# Node module not installing

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, node-modules, yarnpkg

When I run yarn while installing the node module, dependencies  on the last stage it is not installing, i get this error. any one help me to fixed this issue
[image]

Comment: Its a warning (says 'warning' in yellow) - Did you read what it says? **To clear this warning, remove package-lock.json**

Comment: Okay I will do it. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to delete `package-lock.json` file
then run `yarn` again
or use `npm` instead

Comment: Okay, Thanks for help. I will check, and let you know.